# jquery select all text when click on element (not input)

Tags: javascript

Hi to select all text in input i use .select function.

```
$('input#name').select()
```

But how can i select  text in div after click?
*// not text() function, i want sth like this: http://jsfiddle.net/UKfT7/289/ (but when click on < pre>)*

```
$('tr td:eq(0) pre').click(function(){$(this).select();});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using select use text() function in jquery,  This might solve your problem -

```
$('tr td:eq(0) pre').click(function(){
  var text = $(this).text();

  });
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the string that `.text()` returns.

Comment: But it's not select text like that http://jsfiddle.net/UKfT7/289/

Comment: I would request to explain a bit more.. and also provide your html code.